# Build documentation for Go 1 on Windows

Tags: windows, documentation, go

How to build Go 1 documentations on Windows?
It is at D:\go\doc on my machine and all links and paths are broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a master on Windows, but Go's documentation does not work like that. You should use [`godoc`](http://golang.org/cmd/godoc/) command for accessing Go documentation. Run `godoc -http=:6060` and access documentation at `http://127.0.0.1:6060` in your browser.

Comment: I have to add 'godoc -http=:6060' has to run from the doc directory.

Comment: [Setting environment variables](http://golang.org/doc/install#install) should fix that.